# Google Maps on website in Android OS

Tags: web, google-maps-api-2

Hello I have this webiste www.liiklusinfo.ee and it's basically designed to work on web browsers, but is it possible to see that map on an Android mobile-phone? I can see that it is possible, because http://kraater.eu/en/map shows up on my android phone, but why isn't my website showing up? When I open the page, it states that I must get a new API code, but I have all the right API keys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely due to the fact that you are using Maps API v2 instead of v3.

> "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&hl=en&sensor=false&key=ABQIAAAAzrzbFLxHQWFbTQr9PqQ_HhRwAQ6CP1ccuJFaeFcXqlGX2NtZ2xQSe3YINEpjxiDi-m_GSubdYtbMEg">

V2 is causing some issues which is preventing v3 from loading. You may be able to find the route of those problems, but it would just be easier to switch to v3.

I would recommend reading this guide:

http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest upgrading to the version [3 api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/), the tag line is *V3: The Solution for Maps Applications for both the Desktop and Mobile Devices* after all.

This should solve your problem.  Moreover, i can see the map on the opera mini browser on my android just not the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate! But as I have discovered that API V3 doesn't need an API key, how can I 'update' my map to v3?